# Macro with breakpoint behaves different

Tags: vba, ms-word

This is giving me headaches.
I have a Word macro that is pretty huge.
And at a certain point I have to change the header and format of the pages.

Hence I insert a break at this point

```
Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakContinuous
```

change to landscape/horizontal format (cause the images have also this format)

```
    WordBasic.TogglePortrait Tab:=3, PaperSize:=0, TopMargin:="2.5", _
    BottomMargin:="2.5", LeftMargin:="2", RightMargin:="2.5", Gutter:="0", _
    PageWidth:="29.7", PageHeight:="21", Orientation:=1, FirstPage:=0, _
    OtherPages:=0, VertAlign:=0, ApplyPropsTo:=0, FacingPages:=0, _
    HeaderDistance:="1.25", FooterDistance:="1.25", SectionStart:=0, _
    OddAndEvenPages:=0, DifferentFirstPage:=0, Endnotes:=0, LineNum:=0, _
    StartingNum:=1, FromText:=wdAutoPosition, CountBy:=0, NumMode:=0, _
    TwoOnOne:=0, GutterPosition:=0, LayoutMode:=0, CharsLine:=41, LinesPage:= _
    39, CharPitch:=220, LinePitch:=360, DocFontName:="+Textkörper", _
    DocFontSize:=11, PageColumns:=1, TextFlow:=0, FirstPageOnLeft:=0, _
    SectionType:=1, FolioPrint:=0, ReverseFolio:=0, FolioPages:=1
```

enter the header

```
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
```

the pages before shouldn't be changed so unlink the header formation with the previous

```
Selection.HeaderFooter.LinkToPrevious = False
```

Jump out of the header go to the last page = the first page of the new section
This needs to be done otherwise I am in the header of the previous section due to the above command. (Dont know why it jumps into the last header) and jump into the correct header

```
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
Selection.EndKey unit:=wdStory
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
```

Select the whole header and delete it

```
Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Delete
```

Everything works fine if i set a breakpoint after changing to horizontal format means first time I jump into the header or at an earlier point of the above listed. But this is the last possible one.

Without the breakpoint instead of deleting only the header of the last page also the headers of the previous section are deleted.

I don't know why this happens or how to prevent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out how to do it.
I already thought that it has something to do with the runtime and that some events couldn't be executed in time.

so i wrote a loop with doevents

```
For u = 1 To 1000000
DoEvents
Next u
```

This is too much I know but it works ;)

edit:
Actually 2 times is enough no need for 1000000 I just wanted to be sure in the beginning :D

Comment: You could try turning off ScreenUpdating at the beginning of the macro (`Application.ScreenUpdating = False`) and turning it on again at the end (`Application.ScreenUpdating = True`). That way Word does not have to update the screen, and maybe the timing of the macro will work better.

Comment: I used me.application.visible = false in the beginning and set it to true at the end. But this didn't help as well ;)